# how to pass output of multiple files to an array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, lda

I am trying to run lda model on my files. Firstly I did some preprocessing like tokenization and stop word removal. I am doing this for multiple files, but when I pass the final output to lda model it gives me an error and I saw in Google that lda takes multiple files as an input.
Now I want to  store the output of each file to an array and then pass that array as an input but it is also giving me an error IndexError: list assignment index out of range. I don't know what is the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

```
   # URDU STOP WORDS REMOVAL
    doc_clean = []
    stopwords_corpus = UrduCorpusReader('./data', ['stopwords-ur.txt'])    
    stopwords = stopwords_corpus.words()
    count = 1
    # print(stopwords)
    for infile in (wordlists.fileids()):
        words = wordlists.words(infile)
        finalized_words = remove_urdu_stopwords(stopwords, words)
        doc_clean[count] = finalized_words
        print(doc_clean)
        count =count+1
        print("\n==== WITHOUT STOPWORDS ===========\n")
        print(finalized_words)
        id2word = corpora.Dictionary(doc_clean)
        mm = [id2word.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]
        lda = models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=mm, id2word=id2word, num_topics=3, update_every=1, chunksize=10000, passes=1)
```

Comment: At which line does the error occure? Do you have a stacktrace?
I suppose, the problem is starting with `count=1`. Later you call `doc_clean[count]` which obviously starts with index 1 instead of 0

Comment: Use `doc_clean.append(finalized_words)` where `append` is a list method for adding items into the list.

Comment: @MaxM It will still give error since in an empty list you can't access or add elements like this.

Comment: suppose i want to add output of textfile1 ,textfile2 and so on to an array.     like this doc_clean =[textfile1,textfile2....].will apend do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use `count` variable here. List provides `append` function to add elements into a list.
Change this

```
  doc_clean[count] = finalized_words
```

To this

```
 doc_clean.append(finalized_words)
```

Comment: it worked but it combine all the output of text files in one place.how can i do this doc_clean = [doc1,doc2,doc3,doc3.....]

Comment: @user3778289  `doc_clean.append([finalized_words])` do this

Comment: i did it.but it is combining all the files in one file.

Answer (score 0):

You define doc_clean as empty list, but in the first iteration you reference doc_clean[count] with count=1, so to the second element of an empty list.

Replace the

```
doc_clean[count]=finalized_words
```

with

```
doc_cleanappend(finalized_words)
```

Then there is not use of count anymore.

Comment: doc_clean.append(finalized_words).this will make an array?like if my output is like of some files like textfile1,textfile2 and so on.this append will add the all??